# How to display a query from a phpmyadmin that uses MariaDB? My query returns empty

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Can someone please explain to me how to display a query from a phpmyadmin that uses MariaDB? When I execute this script, the page returns empty. No error messages, nothing. All blank [screenshot of the phpamydmin here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDzMv.png).

It seems the commands I shall use in PHP must be different from the used in the conventional phpmyadmin.

I've searched in different sites, but it seems MariaDB is not much used.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
$dbuser = 'santos1q_test';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test';

mysql_select_db('santos1q_events');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo {$row['event_title']};
    echo {$row['event_address']};
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: are you saying that the PHP script works successfully? And what did you run in PHPMyAdmin? Just "SELECT * FROM test"? P.S. The mysql_ library is deprecated, and removed in PHP7. It's also not very secure. I suggest you use mysqli_ or PDO if you are writing new code.

Comment: thx for the reply. I am saying actually that the phpmyadmin doesnt return my  request. I created an index.html file and put only this script on it. And when I  open the page it is all blank.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. How is this script relevant to phpMyAdmin? phpMyAdmin is a pre-defined product. It contains UI to allow you to run any query you like, and to maintain your database using GUI elements instead of query scripts, if you prefer. Are you saying you tried to integrate your own PHP into the product? Because that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Sorry my technical language is poor... i am pretty new to this coding world.
I created the dabatase with no problem at all. The problem is that I want to display the database info in my webpage using PHP script but I could not make it. Instead of my "index.html" showing the result or even an error message, the screen is simply blank.

Comment: ..but your screenshot of your "blank" page includes the PHPmyAdmin sidebar. That's why I'm confused. Why is that appearing, if the script is separately in your own website? I assumed that you had copied index.html into the phpMyAdmin folder and run it from there. One other thing - what happens if you rename the file to "index.php" and run it like that? .html normally means a static page, not a script file, and the webserver may not pass the request to the PHP engine.

Comment: the screenshot is the mainpage of the phpmyadmin, located inside the cpanel of my webhosting provider;
the script is written in the index.html file;
when I access the index.html (as an end user) the page comes blank

Comment: ok. so why is the screenshot relevant to your script? Is there a link between them? And did you try my suggestion to rename the file to index.php?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the site returns the error 500 (is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500).

And the screenshot contains info about the phpmyadmin specs, like version. I thought it could give a clue of what the problem was. 

Do you think there's something wrong with the script I wrote? thx!

Comment: there is nothing obviously wrong with the script. But, to test, create another page "test.php" which is just `<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>` and nothing else. Then try to run that and see what result you get. If it prints "Hello World" in the page then PHP is working ok. But if you get another error, there maybe something wrong with the server setup

Comment: your script worked. Probably it is related to the server setup. In the previous web hosting companies all was set, and I just needed to feed the tables. 

Many thanks! I wish I can someday contribute to the developer's world as much as nice people like you do :)

Comment: you can always ask the host provider if there are any errors in the PHP logs for your account. That might give you a better clue. I did point out above that the mysql_ library you are using is out of date. Possibly they have blocked it, or you are running PHP7. Try changing to mysqli_ or PDO as I suggested (plenty of tutorials available online) and see if that helps

Comment: P.S. we all have to learn somehow (mainly by trial and error!). I'm sure in a few years you will be helping people out as well - good luck.

Comment: HI ADyson, I managed to display a query on my site :)
If it will be useful to someone, I found the script here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

The query is displaying twice, but (I believe) it is just a matter of time to adjust this. 

Thx again and have a blessed 2017!